# pybind11 passing numpy array to C++ jumbles up elements

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ function that takes in three 1D numpy arrays as an input:

```
py::array_t<double> myFunc( py::array_t<double> xcoords, py::array_t<double> ycoords, py::array_t<double> zcoords, const int nparts)
{
    // process numpy array inputs from the python side
    auto buf2 = xcoords.request();
    double *x = (double *)buf2.ptr;

    auto buf3 = ycoords.request();
    double *y = (double *)buf3.ptr;

    auto buf4 = zcoords.request();
    double *z = (double *)buf4.ptr;

    // allocate mem for the output numpy array
    py::array_t<double> result = py::array_t<double>(nbins);
    auto buf5 = result.request();
    // c++ counterpart of the result array
    double *hist = (double *)buf5.ptr;

    // var declarations
    int i;

    
    // loop over all points
    for (i = 0; i < nparts; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << x[i] << " " << y[i] << " " << z[i] << std::endl;
         
        // do stuff to populate elements of result
    }

    return result;
}
```

I create these three arrays in python by:

```
points = np.random.rand(N,3) * L
```

and pass into the function

```
res = module.myFunc(points[:,0], points[:,1], points[:,2], 10)
```

An example set of values would be:

```
4.6880498641905195 0.335265721430103 4.095097368241972
1.287345441223418 0.18213643934310575 1.9076717100770817
3.9083692529696985 3.58692445785723 1.2090842532316792
2.0727395137272273 0.8991931179824342 3.428767449961339
2.8468968826288634 4.935019700055825 1.8476045204842446
2.2248370075368733 4.684880446417251 3.7368688164101376
3.4876671749517643 1.7266611398614629 0.22011783388784623
1.5372784463757512 4.6664761047248575 4.148012219052029
3.10720337544295 4.670106619033467 2.8297722540139763
```

Which is what the python code prints out when I check the values in `points`. However, the C++ code produces the following output:

```
0 4.68805 0.335266 4.0951
1 0.335266 4.0951 1.28735
2 4.0951 1.28735 0.182136
3 1.28735 0.182136 1.90767
4 0.182136 1.90767 3.90837
5 1.90767 3.90837 3.58692
6 3.90837 3.58692 1.20908
7 3.58692 1.20908 2.07274
8 1.20908 2.07274 0.899193
9 2.07274 0.899193 3.42877
```

The values somehow become jumbled up. `points[1,0]` ends up duplicating `points[0,1]`, etc. It looks like a silly memory/indexing problem, but I can't figure it out. What am I missing?

**Edit:** There's a statement in the documentation that says: "Data in NumPy arrays is not guaranteed to packed in a dense manner; furthermore, entries can be separated by arbitrary column and row strides. Sometimes, it can be useful to require a function to only accept dense arrays using either the C (row-major) or Fortran (column-major) ordering. This can be accomplished via a second template argument with values `py::array::c_style` or `py::array::f_style`."

So instead of `array_t<double>`, I put `<double, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>`. It seems to work. I don't understand why numpy entries can be jumbled up by default. I would appreciate any insight into this strange behavior.

Comment: As I can see from your prints, probably you got the numpy array in a 'Fortrat ordering' (column-major), and in your code in C++ you access it like a C array (row-major). 

You can see it if you change your code to:
`
        std::cout << i << " " << x[3*i] << " " << y[3*i] << " " << z[3*i] << std::endl;
`

Comment: @ykaner I thought the default numpy array ordering was C. Within the python code, it works as C-ordering. Why would it get converted to Fortran ordering while being transferred to the C++ code?

Comment: You don't know it's physical (in memory) ordering in python since python is a high level language. So if you write `a[x][y]` you don't know what calculation python apply on `x` and `y` to get the real address of what you want.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the best practice would be to always force C type ordering in the method definition in C++?